What is the Simplest Way to Hash Some Value and then Iteratively Hash the Result?
I'm trying to manually verify that an old  Electrum bitcoin wallet of mine contains keys that were derived from its seed as expected. One step in the key derivation requires that I hash the seed via Sha256, and then hash the result again via Sha256, and then hash that result via Sha256, etc, until there have been 100000 iterations. Ideally, I would like to do it within a bash shell, since that is really the only environment that I'm somewhat competent in, but if that isn't possible, or if there is a superior way to do it in some other context, I'm willing to try to learn/attempt.
I have been searching for an answer to this for several hours now...it seems all the Google results are about whether or not iterative hashing has any value in terms of security...but I have failed to find any examples of how to actually do it. Any help would be very much appreciated.
The seed that I need to hash is basically, for example: AABBCCDDEEFF1122
I need to hash the raw binary data (not the ascii hex string itself), so my input is basically: "echo 'AABBCCDDEEFF1122' | xxd -r -p" and then I need to pipe the output of that command to something else that will hash it via SHA256, then take the result (the raw data, not the ascii hex characters) and hash that via SHA256, and then hash that result via SHA256 etc, etc, until there have been 100000 iterations. The final SHA256 hash result is supposed to be the master private key that I need to complete/double check the key derivation.
The only elementary attempt I have made so far to do that nyself was a primitive solution that basically consisted of the following: I created an executable called 'hash10times' that contained "sha256sum | xxd -r -p" x10. Then I created another executable called "hash100times" that contained "hash10times | xxd -r -p" 10x..and so on. It worked up until I got to hash10000times...then q bunch of fork errors started piling up...so as you can see I am in pretty serious need of assistance before someone gets hurt.

I suggest you rewrite your question with example input and expected output.  It's sounds like you just need to loop 100000 along these lines: input=...; for((i=0; i < 100000; i++)) { input=hassh(input); } then you define a hash function that transforms your input to output.

There may be existing tools already so you should tag this bitcoin or maybe ask this on the bitcoin community instead?

Are 100000 iterations good? After the first iteration the are 2^256 possible results. With each iteration, some/many source values are mapped to the same new SHA256 value. So each iteration reduces the number of possible values. That means for example, that Harry and John can have the same SHA256 after 70000 iterations. And so John becomes a valid password for the original Harry.

@Wiimm Iterative hashing is a very common and classical technique which primary goal is to increase the cost of exhaustive search. So yes, in many situations, it is "good". And 100000 (a bit less than 2^17) is so small, compared to the 2^256 state space, that the probability to find a collision with the technique you describe (start with 2 different input messages and iterate until the 2 digests are equal) is also extremely small. Else collisions would have already been found and using SHA256 would have been discouraged long time ago.

@Alan Thank you for the response! I suspected I may need to use "for," but I am not very familiar with it at all. Can you elaborate on "then you define a hash function"? The hash method I need to use is Sha256. How do I define that?

@Alan I did want to give an example of an input and expected outcome, but I don't know how to give an example of the expected outcome without being able to generate it (it would just be another Sha256 hash). Also, I have experimented with a few different cryptocurrency-centric tools, but the problem is this particular key derivatiok step is in a rather outdated and now unsupported version of Electrum, so finding tools for it has proven difficult (for me, anyway)

You need to use @AllanWind if you want me to see your comments.  Maybe you define your hash function in terms of openssl sha256?  I don't know how your input and output looks like so not sure I will be able to guide you more than that.

@AllanWind Sorry, I looked at the comment formatting page and it said I could just use first names and it would work...it didn't specify that I had to spell it right, too! Lol.

@AllanWind My input is just a binary representation of a hex string. I'll update my Q with that info right now.

hi What is the Simplest Way why "simplest"? Why not just do it "any" way and be done with it? Are you specifically searching for "simplest" way to do it? Is "simplest" a solution with the least number of characters, how to score it? It worked up until I got to hash10000times...then q bunch of fork errors started piling up Please post yourscript and please post exact full verbatim all messages from the execution of your script. What "bunch of fork errors" did you see exactly?

Bash is probably less than ideal because sha256 et al. returns a hex representation instead of the actual value. The majority of your run time will be spent converting the hex hashes back to binary using some other external tool; you might as well learn enough Python (or Perl, Ruby, etc) to write the whole thing in that.

Also, why or what is the point of running 100000 iterations of hashing?

See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10235161/how-to-iteratively-sha256-in-python-using-native-lib-ie-hashlib-using-byte for a simple Python solution (though obviously with a different number of iterations).

@KamilCuk This is known as key stretching. It basically requires a fair amount of work to just validate a password, making it more work to mount a brute-force attack. (Mind, newer algorithms solve this in a different manner.)

@tripleee I didn't realize that it was converting all the outputs to a hex string in the background...that makes sense though, and explains why running the example provided by KamilCuk takes so long to run at 100000 iterations (on my 2012 iMac, anyway). But it does work, which is awesome! And I really only needed to do it once, anyway.

@KamilCuk Thank you so much! It works! Unfortunately I can't upvote anything because I'm too much of a newb. You have saved me countless more hours of searching. Cannot thank you enough. And thank you to everyone that responded!

@RenaudPacalet In your calculation you assume that there is only one duplicate per run. But what if there is 1 duplicate or more per billion checksums? And that happens in each of the 100,000 runs. However, I don't think we can calculate it in this way.

@Wiimm I don't understand your reasoning. Do you mean that cryptographic hash functions like SHA256 have a lower resistance against collisions than what cryptographers think? This is quite interesting.

@Wiimm There is no reduction after the first iteration. If the hash for "John" would be equal to the hash for "Harry" in the first place then of course it will also be the same after n iterations. I think you are assuming that subsequent iterations will converge towards some value but by design, it shouldn't (and if indeed it does, that's a groundbreaking discovery, as alluded to by Renaud).

@AnarchyMyDear : if you're so concerned about security you need to re-hash something 100,000 times, perhaps mix and match various other hash algorithms that's somewhat orthogonal to SHA256, because if, by some very unlucky turn of events, someone found an inherent weakness in SHA256 as an algorithm, that would make your bitcoin keys vulnerable, regardless of how many iterations you throw at it.

@AnarchyMyDear : but i'm really impressed your 12-year-old mac is still humming along


I need to hash the raw binary data (not the ascii hex string itself), so my input is basically: "echo 'AABBCCDDEEFF1122' | xxd -r -p" and then I need to pipe the output of that command to something else that will hash it via SHA256, then take the result (the raw data, not the ascii hex characters) and hash that via SHA256, and then hash that result via SHA256 etc, etc, until there have been 100000 iterations. The final SHA256 hash result is supposed to be the master private key that I need to complete/double check the key derivation.

It looks like a loop:
tmp=AABBCCDDEEFF1122
for ((i=0;i<10;++i)); do
   tmp=$(echo "$tmp" | xxd -r -p | sha256sum | awk '{print $1}');
done
echo "$tmp"


If this solved your problem, please consider accepting it. If you prefer, you are welcome to post an answer of your own, and accepting that. Accepting an answer helps future visitors by marking your problem as resolved. See also help.

As echo is not standard printf '%s' "$tmp" is maybe be a bit safer. And using an array for tmp would avoid awk: tmp=(AABBCCDDEEFF1122 -) and then: tmp=($(printf '%s' "$tmp" | xxd -r -p | sha256sum)).

hi @RenaudPacalet I agree. But I do not think there is much point in optimization. A similar trivial python script will most probably run millions times faster. | echo is standard, options to echo are not standarized.

Agreed, optimizing a bash loop when python would do the job is pointless. As for echo, besides the options, I think the handling of backslash characters in strings also varies between versions. But I also agree that, in this specific case, it shouldn't matter. Note that POSIX now says "New applications are encouraged to use printf instead of echo".
